# two equivalent definitions for solvable groups

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

Suppose I have a finite group G that is solvable. So we know this means $G^{(n)}$=1 for some $n \geq 0$. We can then write

$1=H_0 \triangleright H_1 \triangleright...\triangleright H_s=G  $ such that $G^{(n-i)}=H_i$ and $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is abelian.

An equivalent definition for solvability would be:

$1=K_0 \triangleright K_1 \triangleright...\triangleright K_s=G$  and $K_{i+1}/K_i$ is cyclic.

Knowing $G^{(n-i)}=H_i$, is there a way to define $K_i$ in terms of $H_i$?

Comment: Do you know the classification of finite abelian groups?  You would have that each $H_{i + 1}/H_i$ is a sum of cyclic groups.  You could adjust $H_i$ to get a cyclic group instead.  But, there is no canonical way to do it.

Comment: I know that by the structure theorem for abelian groups, since $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is abelian, than it is equivalent to a direct product of cyclic groups.  But i'm not sure how to adjust $H_{i+1}/H_i$ so that it becomes cyclic.

Comment: You would just take the decomposition of $H_{i + 1}/H_i$ into cyclic groups, select one of the factors to preserve, then increase the size of $H_i$ to cancel out the other factors.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 can you give me more details or a concrete example please. Im not sure I understand correctly.

Comment: That is only an equivalent definition of a solvability for fintie groups, not for grouups in general.

Comment: yes, but I said I was working with finite groups at the beginning of my statement. @DerekHolt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can always refine the first sequence. Assume that $G$ is finite and $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is abelian. Then by the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups

$$H_{i+1}/H_i \simeq C_{\alpha_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus C_{\alpha_k}$$

where each $C_{\alpha_j}$ is cyclic. By the third isomorphism theorem

$$C_{\alpha_j}\simeq H_{i+1}^j/H_i$$

for some subgroups $H_{i} < H_{i+1}^j < H_{i+1}$. Thus you can easily refine the sequence by putting

$$H_i < H_{i+1}^1 < H_{i+1}^1\oplus H_{i+1}^2 < \cdots <  H_{i+1}^1\oplus\cdots\oplus H_{i+1}^k = H_{i+1}$$

Consecutive quotients are isomorphic to $C_{\alpha_j}$ thus they are cyclic.